# Can't post status as a page using page token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have set-up a Facebook page and I'm trying to use a Facebook app to post as the page on the page itself.

Using the user token I have got the page access_token and confirmed it has permissions defined in the perms array e.g.

```
"perms": [
   "ADMINISTER",
   "EDIT_PROFILE",
   "CREATE_CONTENT",
   "MODERATE_CONTENT",
   "CREATE_ADS",
   "BASIC_ADMIN"
 ]
```

As far as I can see in the documentation the required permissions are manage_pages and publish_pages, both of which are granted as can be seen using the /{user_id}/permissions endpoint.

```
{
  "data": [
    ...
    {
      "permission": "email",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "manage_pages",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "publish_pages",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I've also checked using the access token debugger which confirms the token is valid and has the following scopes:

```
user_friends, read_page_mailboxes, email, manage_pages, publish_pages, public_profile
```

If I then do a call using the page access_token to the page, I can see the extra information available to admins, including "can_post" being set to true, however when I do a POST request to post to the feed for example using POST /{page_id}/feed?access_token={page_access_token} it returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "CQqJd1hfnMm"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated at this point!

Comment: What API version are you using? `publish_pages` was introduced with v2.3, before that you need to use `publish_actions`.

Comment: @CBroe You were correct! I actually spoke to a Facebook developer about it as well, it was working for me as a developer but was using a previous API version for the actual site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be an issue with the API version being used, forcing the endpoint to use v2.3 or above fixed the issue as `manage_pages` was only introduced then. Unfortunately the error wasn't very descriptive about this!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get "publish_pages" permission from your app.

Comment: I did have publish_pages permissions as can be seen above, the issue turned out to be with the API version.

Comment: By the error

    The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action",

It seems user did not gave permission. If its API version problem means different error will come right?

Comment: and Publish_action will work for posting in user or page try this.

Comment: No unfortunately it gives the same error, which is why I didn't think to look at the API version.